# How can I fix SharePoint Document is not modified?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

When the users Want to Modified Microsoft Word in SharePoint, they are getting the following error:

> Error message, we
>   can't connect to 'https://d.docs./Users/**/***/Documents/xxx'. Please
>   make sure you're using the correct web address

Note: the( link works) this after document modified

Comment: Do you try to modify the document via browser or via word client?  Do you get this error for all users and all documents or specific users?

Comment: Specific Users !